# Запуск конкретных тестов (cucumber + capybara with poltergeist)

Tags: test-automation, cucumber, capybara

Добрый день!
Начал использовать фреймворк [BDDfire](https://github.com/Shashikant86/bddfire) для написания интеграционных тестов своих проектов.

- Имеются два разных проекта, с собой никак не связанных.
- Имеется отдельный репозиторий, где для данных проектов описаны соответствующие тесты.
- Для каждого проекта имеются файлы с фичами (*.features) и файлы с
  шагами реализации (step_definitions.rb). То есть по два файла на
  каждый проект.
- При запуске тестов командой **rake poltergeist** выполняются все тесты.
- Я, в свою очередь, хочу запускать тесты отдельно для каждого проекта.
- В документации к cucumber, capybara, BDDfire пока ничего не нашлось.

Прошу помощи, если кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей и успешно ее решил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете пометить разные features и scenarios тегами (@project1, @project2 и т.п.) и немного изменить rakefile. Добавив в него вот это

```
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:poltergeist_project1) do |t|
  // имя может быть любым ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  t.cucumber_opts = 'features -p poltergeist --format pretty --profile html -t ~@api -t @project1'
  // это тег который вы добавили   ->                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
end
```

Тогда при

```
rake poltergeist_project1
```

будут выполнены тесты помеченные тегом `@project1`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сейчас попробую!